# How can I segment a mySQL fulltext table?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a mysql table with fulltext. Every day its size will increase by 30K data items. I am afraid the query speed will decrease when the data size increases to many GB. My situation permits me to limit the search to the most recent one million data items.

First I tried `partitioning table`, but mysql does not supprt `fulltext` and `partition` at the same time.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html

Some friends suggest I use another dbms product, such as `sphinx`, `solr`, or `oracle`. But I'd rather use mySQL, for budget reasons. (Forgive my stubbornness).

So, how can I optimize mysql fulltext table searches? how can I keep an acceptable query speed as the volume of my data scales up?

1. divide table? (then make query complex)
2. only limit query by id? `SELECT * FROM table  WHERE (MATCH (some_field) AGAINST ('+search_words' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND id>last_id-1000000 AND id<last_id Order By date DESC`
3. another good suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a few more details about the text items you're searching?  Will each text item have a timestamp? If your application only needs the last million items to be searchable, does that mean you can delete older items?

Comment: hi @Ollie Jones, the `text items` are 2 part, one stored words with `srcwd` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, another is date `date ` int(10) NOT NULL, with UNIX timestamp. I will keep the older items. I also could query them by `id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to handle your problem. It's not super-beautiful but it will be quite efficient.

Create two copies of your table.  Call one something like `text_current` and the second something like `text_archive`.

Load your newly arriving rows of data into `text_current`.  That way your current data will be  available for search.

Write two stored procedures: one called something like `copy_text` that selects older rows from `text_current` and inserts them into `text_archive`, and another called something like `purge_text` that deletes the older rows from `text_current`.  Then, run those two stored procedures from mySql jobs.

If I were you I would run the `copy_text` job once every night at 03:00, and copy every item that arrived any time in the previous day (midnight to midnight).

I would run the  `purge_text` job once a week, and purge everything from `text_current` that is more than 35 days old. (It takes 33.3 days to get a million records at 30K records a day).

This method of migrating your data from a current table to an archive table has some handy features.

1. It's safe -- most records are in both the current and archived
   tables.
2. It's deterministic -- using dates rather than ids lets you
   select items for archiving precisely.
3. It offers, for the future, if you need it, a slow but effective "search the archives" feature in
   your product.
4. It keeps the size of your current data table
   relatively workable while allowing you the use of mySql's fine full text search feature.
5. It is efficient -- the hard work of migrating is done in one go each day, rather than continuously by mucking about with id numbers in your queries.

Here's how to select records by date, when the `record_date` column is a unix time stamp. If you run this on any given day, it will select records from midnight on the previous day, up to *but not including* records at midnight on the present day.

```
...
WHERE text_current.record_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND text_current.record_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
...
```

It doesn't matter at what time of day you run this query, it always runs midnight to midnight.  That's the beauty of `CURDATE()` -- it means midnight today. (`NOW()` means, well, now; it's like `CURDATE()` but also has a time. But you don't want that because you want to do your archiving midnight-to-midnight.  If you use `NOW()` you'll get caught by small unpredictabilities in when you run your stored procedures.

(Don't be tempted to use the `BETWEEN` operator for time ranges; it's inclusive and you want the end time of your time range not to be inclusive.)

Similarly, if you want to delete everything that's older than 35 days, do this.

```
DELETE 
 FROM text_current
 WHERE text_current.record_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 35 DAY))
```

See how this goes?  When you do your archiving and purging, you're always selecting records based on the DAY they were inserted, regardless of the TIME they were inserted.  That's what I mean by deterministic.

Comment: I understand your meaning, your suggestion is suit for me. one more question, `It's deterministic -- using dates rather than ids lets you select items for archiving precisely.` so what is the efficiently `sql query` to match out the nearly 30K items per day? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date<strtotime("-3 hours") AND date>strtotime("-14 hours")` 3 hours because shell code run at 03:00. And should I need set a `fulltext index` for `date` only?(now my fulltext index is `text and date`). Many thanks.